# API Calling Timeout after 10 Seconds in jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, settimeout, connection-timeout

Am working in jQuery mobile and PhoneGap. 
Currently am facing a big issue which still existing. I searched and applied lot of methods but still problem existing. 
My Problem is when I call an API its timeout after 10 Seconds. So its not getting result in iPhone versions.. but Its return result in Android (In the case of android its also shows timeout but i get its result.)

I Tried Timeout methods in jQuery Ajax call.. but :-(

**Here is my code ;**

```
function proceed_payment(){
var cardholder_= $('#input_Cardholder_name_').val();
var card_num_ = $('#input_CreditCard_').val();
var payment_ =$('#card_type_').val();
var cvv2_=$('#input_cvv2_').val();
var url;

if(showmond_value==0)
{
    url='https://www.sample.com/json/save_pament.php?json=1& reserv_num='+reservation_number+'&callback='+reservation_carcompany+'&cardholder='+cardholder_+'&payment='+payment_+'&card_num='+card_num_+'&card_cvv2='+cvv2_+'&card_expire_mon='+expire_month+'&card_expire_year='+expire_year+'&org_deposit='+sCarDeposit+'&org_cur='+currency+'&mond='+company_Show_mond+''
}

$.ajax({  
  url:url,
  data:'',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  timeout: 15000,
  crossDomain:true,
  cache: false,
  async:false,

  success:function(data)
  { 
     alert(data.Status);
  }
}); 

};
```

**Time out Screen shot(checking in Eclipse)..**

[image]

Comment: Question - what version of jQuery are you using? FYI, async: false is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Am using jQuery v1.8.3. :-(

Comment: Ok, just figured I'd mention that. Your call is being made asynchronously, something great to be aware of :)

Comment: @ p e p : i changed async:false  to async:true. but still its timeout!

Comment: Yep, that's a whole other issue. I just wanted to make sure you knew about the deprecated option

Comment: @ p e p: so how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: `async:true` is the only way. It wont kill asynchronous calls even if it takes 100s.

Comment: @ 2-Stroker : we already tried async:true but issue is still existing.

Comment: @ULLASMOHAN.V You should not get that error issue if it is `async:true`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `ExternalHosts` property of your iPhone project's `PhoneGap.plist` file to `*` to whitelist requests to external domains.

You can also try adding the following code to your JS file to guarantee that cross-domain requests are enabled for the jQuery framework when it's executed in the webView.

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});
```

Also, at least in earlier versions of jQuery there were issues with jsonp timeout errors being ignored (and I think setting `crossDomain:true` in your `$.ajax` call can cause fallback to jsonp in jQuery mobile). So you could try using the following plugin: [jQuery-JSONP](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp):

> jQuery-JSONP is a compact (1.8kB minified), yet feature-packed,
>   alternative solution to jQuery's implementation of JSONP.
>
> [...]
>
> jQuery-JSONP features:
>
> - a timeout mechanism.

Which would turn your call into something along the lines of the following (note the use of the `$.jsonp` function instead of `$.ajax`:

```
$.jsonp({
    "url": url,
    "data": "",
    "datatype": "json"
    "timeout": 15000,
    "success": function(data) {
        alert(data.Status);
    },
    "error": function(d,msg) {
        alert("Could not find user "+userId);
    }
});
```

Comment: jsonp also occur same issue :(

Comment: Did you attempt the other two solutions I mentioned? In my opinion they are both more likely given that your problems are specific to the iPhone and not Android. Also, I notice that you are requesting a url from an SSL domain - are you sure the certificate being served is valid and you've accepted it on the Safari browser? Cross-domain AJAX HTTPS requests using invalid certificates from the server will silently fail and thus will halt JS execution without triggering an error callback in your client-side code.

Comment: we checked in Safari browser. its takes 12 seconds to respond. but its works fine in safari browser. but fails in device

Comment: @ULLASMOHAN.V : Did you fix this issue?